# Subquery returning multiple rows in coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

This may seem a little dumb question but what happens if I have a subquery in `COALESCE` which returns 2 records like this:

```
select
coalesce(<some subquery>,'') as "result",
column2, column3, .....
from <table name>
```

Now if the subquery returns 2 results what will the output of whole query?

Comment: It would be easy for you to test it... use "select 1 test union select 2" as the subquery.

Comment: hmmm ... try it, and report back.

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error saying that the subquery returns more than 1 row.